# Appstoreconnect payments not what they should be

Tags: app-store-connect, apple-developer

Does the appstoreconnect sales take in account people who have refunded? Because in one month my sales were $77,20, proceeds were $45,22 and the actual payment to my bank was $41,8. Shouldn't the apple fee be 30% so shouldn't the payment be something around $55, or am I just missing something out? The apple search ads were $5 during that month.

Thank you!